# unable to download glassfish 3 from netbeans

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-3, netbeans-6.9

I have centos installed on myserver and for development i have installed NetBeans IDE 6.9.1.

Now as glassfish 3 was not present on my server i tried to download it from netbeans itself using 
add server panel but when i click on download i am getting I/O exception , following is the screen shot
can anyone tell me how to get rid off it ..

[image]

Comment: its been a year and i'm still having same issue

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by some poor programming on my part and the CollabNet to Kenai migration of the java.net web sites.

The url for downloading became something like http://download.java.net/glassfish/... when the migration took place.  6.9.1 had shipped long before the migration took place and remapping this URL did not get put on 'the list' of URLs that had to be remapped.

Some of the coding problems have been addressed in 7.0 builds.  Since 7.0 is nearly FCS, you may want to consider using those builds instead of 6.9.1...

Note: you download GlassFish Server Open Source Edition with the following link: http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/3.0.1/release/glassfish-3.0.1-ml.zip